# double quote in json simple

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I want this outcome:

```
{"link":[{"url":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript", "label":"wikipedia"}]}
```

I tried this:

```
JSONObject ob1 = new JSONObject();
ob1.put("link","[{\"url\":\"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript\", label:\"wikipedia\"}]");
```

The output of ob1.toJSONString() is:

```
{"link":"[{\"url\":\"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/JavaScript\", label:\"wikipedia\"}]"}
```

What am I doing wrongly?
I am using json-simple-1.1.1

Answer (score 0):

You should put a JSONArray into the JSONObject and in the Array again a JSONObject with the keys/values `"url"/"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript"` and `"label"/"wikipedia"`

```
JSONObject ob1 = new JSONObject();
JSONArray ar1 = new JSONArray();
ob1.put ("link", ar1);

JSONObject ob2 = new JSONObject();
ar1.add(ob2);

ob2.put("url", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript");
ob2.put("label", "wikipedia");
```

In case you have the value of ob1 link object already as JSON string then you can first interpret this into a JSONArray using

```
JSONArray ar1 = (JSONArray)JSONValue.parse(yourJSONStr);
```

**NOTE:** Your intended result is not a JSON string, because for that all `"/"` must be escaped `"\/"`

Comment: Ah that was dumb of me. the problem with the url still exists. I am getting the following and I can't escape the / with \/. {"link":[{"url":"http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org\/wiki\/JavaScript","label":"wikipedia"}]}

Comment: That is JSON spec. Your string would not be a correct JSON formatted string.

Comment: so it is not possible to get my desired outcome?

Comment: I don't think so, because json-simple is following the JSON specification.